# extending a class with the same function

Tags: php, codeigniter

if i have a class that has a index function and i extend it and create another index function. Will the index function in the extension overwrite the parents index function? also, what is parent::__construct() exactly doing in the second class in a construct?

```
class someclass
{
    public function index()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

class newclass extends someclass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: you could very easily just test this by echo'ing something from both functions.

Comment: true, just being lazy i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do some simple test

```
echo "<pre>";
$b = new B();
$b->index();

echo PHP_EOL;

$c = new C();
$c->index();
```

Output

```
A.A::__construct
B.B::index <-------------- Parent index overwrite 

A.A::__construct   <------ Still calls it anyway
A.A::index         <------ Calls A:index
C.C::index         <------ Calls B:index
```

Classes

```
class A {

    function __construct() {
        echo __CLASS__, ".", __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function index() {
        echo __CLASS__, ".", __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class B extends A {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        echo __CLASS__, ".", __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
class C extends A {

    public function index() {
        parent::index();
        echo __CLASS__, ".", __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code will work like this:

```
$someClass = new someClass;
$newClass = new newClass;

$someClass->index(); //this will output what is written in the index function found in someClass
$newClass->index(); //this will output what is written in the index function found in newClass
```

So the `index()` method in newClass will override the `index()` method in someClass only if `index()` is called from `newClass`

To answer your second question, the `parent::__construct()` will call the construct class from `someClass` when `newClass` is called.

Answer (score 0):

> if i have a class that has a index function and i extend it and create another index function. Will the index function in the extension overwrite the parents index function?

Yes. You need to call `parent::index()` in `newclass::index`'s definition, if you want to.

> also, what is parent::__construct() exactly doing in the second class in a construct?

It will cause a PHP-error, since you didn't define a `__construct` method in your parent class.

If you didn't know for sure, if the parent class has a method, or not (f.ex. in a [trait](http://php.net/trait)), you can check it inside a method with `is_callable('parent::method')`.